# syncing d3.js with THREE.js earth

Tags: javascript, d3.js, three.js, map-projections, d3.geo

I am trying to combine WebGL earth  with d3.geo.satellite projection.

I have managed to to overlay the 2 projections on top of each other and sync rotation, but I am having trouble to sync zooming. When I sync them to match size, WebGL projection gets deformed, but the d3.geo.satellite remains the same. I have tried different combination of projection.scale, projection.distance without much success.

Here is JS fiddle (it take a little while to load the resources). You can drag it to rotate (works well). But if you zoom in (use mousewheel) you can see the problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/nxtwrld/7x7dLj4n/2/

The important code is at the bottom of the script - the scale function.

```
function scale(){
    var scale = d3.event.scale;
    var ratio = scale/scale0;

    // scale projection
    projection.scale(scale);

    // scale Three.js earth
    earth.scale.x = earth.scale.y = earth.scale.z = ratio;
}
```

Comment: I encounter this problem too, but I don't use WebGL Earth, instead I use Three.js. Do you have any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not using WebGL earth either , checking on your jsfiddle is not working anymore, and my assumption of your problem that you want to integrated D3.js with Threejs as a solution for 3d globe.

May I suggest you to try [earthjs](https://github.com/earthjs/earthjs) as your solution. Under the hood it use D3.js v4 & Threejs revision 8x both are the latest, and it can combine between Svg, canvas & threejs(WebGL).

```
    const g = earthjs({padding:60})
    .register(earthjs.plugins.mousePlugin())
    .register(earthjs.plugins.threejsPlugin())
    .register(earthjs.plugins.autorotatePlugin())
    .register(earthjs.plugins.dropShadowSvg(),'dropshadow')
    .register(earthjs.plugins.worldSvg('../d/world-110m.json'))
    .register(earthjs.plugins.globeThreejs('../globe/world.jpg'))
    g._.options.showLakes = false;
    g.ready(function(){
        g.create();
    })
```

above snippet code you can run it from [here](https://earthjs.github.io/09-readme/index1.html).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I will fix the jsFiddle as well.
What I was trying to achieve was syncing the D3 svg layer projection with Three.js WebGL canvas. Earthjs is using canvas to render both, which works well, but it looses the possibilities of SVG.

Comment: Ah I get it, can you [try this demo, svg on top of Threejs](https://earthjs.github.io/09-readme/index1.html), basically I am using another plugin for svg.

Comment: updating my answer  and use plugin for svg.

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks!